# How to show toast from a nonactivity class

Tags: java, android

I want to call a function that displays a toast message in showtoast class that extends activity  from database class which is a nonactivity class. But its showing error.

How can I do this?

```
public class database {

    showtoast objshowtoast = new showtoast();

    objshowtoast.toast ();
}

public class showtoast extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate() {
    }

    public toast() {
        Toast.makeText(showtoast.this, "hi toast executed!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: what error is it showing?

Comment: go for system.out.println or pass context in constutor or so

Comment: @adcom System.out? Better Log.d if you need. Anyway, you can't create an Activity directly (it will not have a context)

Comment: Please, follow Android's code style: https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you pass the context with a constructor ?
Like

```
public class database {

    Context _mContext;

    public database(Context c)
    {
        _mContext = c;
    }

    Toast.makeText(_mContext, "Hello Android", 100).show();

}

public class showtoast extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate() {

       database db = new database(showtoast.this);   // calling the constructor and passing the context.
    }

    public toast() {
        Toast.makeText(showtoast.this, "hi toast executed!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You can write your `toast` method like this in `showtoast`

```
public static void toast(Context c)
{

   Toast.makeText(c, "Hello Toast is displaying", 100).show();
}
```

Call this from activity like

`toast(showtoast .this);`

and from `database` class

`showtoast.toast(_mContext);`

I suggest you not to use a method to display a Toast. It just a single line of code. Why do you need a method for that?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `public void toast()`

Without the return type it's interpreted as a constructor.

Also, you can't create an activity with `new`.

You have to create an Intent and create an activity by using a method on your current activity.

```
// 'this' is the current activity
this.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a lot of issues with the code you posted but am not  getting into those. If the task at hand is just to display a toast from a non activity class, then you need not create an activity for that.

You just need a reference to the application context and pass it to create a toast. You can pass the application context to the non activity class of yours as a constructor parameter.

Comment: Why do you need ApplicationContext for Toast? There's no need.

Comment: You need a context , in case you are trying to show the toast from an activity use it's context otherwise if you are showing it from background then you have to use the application context.

Comment: Yes , that's what i meant. Thanks for converting it into code.